# Powershell switch regex fails when run from script but succeeds in console

Tags: regex, powershell, switch-statement, powershell-2.0

This is running in Powershell v2 on a Windows XP SP3 in a powershell -noprofile.

The Powershell script below works if I copy and paste it into the console but does not work if I run it as a script.  Can anyone see what might be causing that?

The script is as follows (some names have been changed to protect the innocent).

```
#Known Error values to count instances of
$KnownErrorText = @"
Invalid Descriptor Index
Syntax error or access violation
An error occurred while attemping to update a record
Message from LDAP server: Invalid credentials
Error sending data over TCP connection
"@

#Fix the variable so it's an array
$KnownErrorText = $knownErrorText.split("`n")

#output variables
$KnownErrors = @{}
$UnknownErrors = @()

#Generate the hash to contain counts of the the known errors
foreach ($line in $knownErrorText) {$KnownErrors.Add($line,0)}

#Get error lines from the log
$scerrors = Select-String -Path "\\myserver01\d$\logs\application.log" -Pattern "Error"

"$($scerrors.count) errors to process"
$ProcessedErrors = 1

#Look at each error.  Pass the error through a switch to identify whether it's
#a known error or not. If it's Known, increment the appropriate count in the hash
#if it's not known, add it to the unknown errors output variable
foreach ($e in $scerrors) {
    "$($ProcessedErrors)`tProcessing`t$($e.line)"
    $addToUnknown = $true
    "e.line type:`t$($e.line.gettype().name)`tLength$($e.line.length)"
    switch -regex ($knownErrorText) {
             #Look in the text of the current error for the any of the errors in
             #the KnownErrorText array
             #THIS IS THE PART THAT DOESN'T WORK WHEN RUNNING IN A SCRIPT
     {"$($e.line)" -match "^.*$($_).*`$"} {
        Write-host "Matched $($_)" -ForegroundColor Green -BackgroundColor Black
        $KnownErrors.Set_Item($_,([int]$KnownErrors.Get_Item($_))+1)
        $addToUnknown = $false
                    #We found our match so stop 
                    #processing the KnownErrorText array through the switch
        break
     }
     default {
        Write-host "UnMatched`t$($_)" -ForegroundColor Red -BackgroundColor Black
     }
 }

     #If we got through all the KnownErrorText values without finding a match, 
     #add the error to the UnknownErrors array to be displayed
 if ($addToUnknown) {$UnknownErrors += $e}

 $ProcessedErrors++
 if ($ProcessedErrors -ge 5) {break}
 }

#Console reporting
"Known Errors:"
$KnownErrors.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object Value -Descending
""
"$($UnknownErrors.count) Unknown Errors:"
$UnknownErrors | Foreach {$_.line}
```

When I run this as a script (for example if saved to c:\temp\ErrorReporting.ps1 and called with 
`& c:\Temp\ErrorReporting.ps1`

the match portion fails:

`{"$($e.line)" -match "^.*$($_).*`$"}`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is due to the string split operation working differently in script vs in the console.  Pasting into the console might produce different line endings that a saved script file contains (`\r\n` vs just `\n`).  So it would help to specify the `$knownErrorText` array explicitly rather than splitting a string to produce it.

```
$knownErrorText = 'Invalid Descriptor Index',
                  'Syntax error or access violation',
                  ...
```

*Aside:*

You are not using `switch -Regex` as intended.  The standard usage is not to have a scriptblock which is doing a `-match` comparison to define the cases, but to simply provide a regex string which the input is matched against.  For example

```
$myStr = 'abc123'
switch -regex ($myStr)
{
   'abc\d\d\d' { 'abc with 3 numbers'; break }
   'xyz\d\d\d' { 'xyz with 3 numbers'; break }
}
```

If you are doing checks inside of scriptblocks to define the cases, you actually don't need the `-regex` flag at all.

Your goal seems to be to check if `$e.Line` contains any of the known error messages.  If so, then a switch probably isn't the best tool, anyways.  You can do this very simply like below:

```
foreach ($e in $scerrors)
{
   if( $knownErrors |?{$e.Line -match $_} )
   {
      "$($e.Line) matches a known error"
   }
   else
   {
      "$($e.Line) does not match a known error"
   }
}
```

Comment: This construction suffers the same result as the switch construction.  It works fine if pasted into a console window, but fails to evaluate the match when run as a script.

Comment: Perhaps it's the string split that's failing - pasting into the console might result in different line endings than what's in your script file.  Why are you doing a `Split` instead of just defining `$knownErrorText` as an array to begin with?  `$knownErrorText = 'error1', 'error2', 'error3'`

Comment: If the test condition is not a string (in this case an expression), then the -regex switch is ignored.

Comment: It's definitely something to do with that array.  If I set the array using `$knownErrorText = @('Error1','Error2')` then the match works. It was actually only an artifact of my development - the real script will read from a text file so would not have encountered that.  Doh! Still odd to me that it works in the console, but not as a script. I don't think that the answer it's under is correct.  Latkin,  if you'll make a new answer with the string split comment I'll mark that as the answer.

Comment: I'll just append that info to my current answer.  Btw, you don't need to wrap your array in `@( )` in this case, though no harm if you prefer to.

Comment: The -regex was not the problem so I don't want to mark this answer as a correct answer.

Comment: The real problem is how the here-string is split.  By splitting on the newline, there is a left over carriage return left in each string.  A correct way to split this would be ``$KnownErrorText = $KnownErrorText -split "`n" | Foreach {$_.trim()}``.  Latkin - I do want to give you credit for leading me to the answer - The array was where the problem was - but I disagree with your first answer.  The switch -regex combined with the use of a regular expression to create matching instances IS a correct usage.

Comment: I've rearranged it to put the solution to your specific problem at the top, but I'm not removing my other content.  You have indeed used `switch -regex` in an unintended way, and your script could indeed be simplified as I suggest.  This additional feedback should count as a net positive, not as a negative.  Mark as an answer if you feel like it, or not.  I'm not too worried about the 15 points.  Mostly I'm glad that your problem is solved :)